# Cannot check out trunk because of branch renamed

Tags: svn, merge

I did not see a post for this particular problem. When checking out the trunk with subversion I got the following error:

```
Retrieving operation 'http://mylink.com.fr/svnroot/myproject/trunk' failed.  svn: E170000: URL 'http://mylink.com.fr/svnroot/myproject/branches/myprojectV3/src/main/resources/com/tech/conversion' at revision 7795 doesn't exist
The checkout does not check all the content of the trunk for this reason.
```

This branch http://mylink.com.fr/svnroot/myproject/branches/myprojectV3 was renamed to http://mylink.com.fr/svnroot/myproject/branches/myprojectT0V3. The revision 7795 refers to the latest commit.
From eclipse I can see the following properties on the trunk:
Svn:mergeinfo  |  /branches/myprojectT0V3:7734,7746,7778
Why there are still references to the branches/myprojectT0V3? This branch was supposed to be renamed.  How can I fix this problem of checking out the trunk?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of a folder with svn:external link. I deleted that link to the branch myprojectV3.
The solution is on this link : [How do I properly remove an svn:externals and replace it with a local (non-external) copy of the same directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044649/how-do-i-properly-remove-an-svnexternals-and-replace-it-with-a-local-non-exter)